# Best practice to return values in different types in a TypeScript object?

Tags: typescript

I made a function that returns the prices of some resources for a game. Those resources can be identified with name or an id, so in my function I added a third parameter allowing someone to specify what type do they want in the returned value.

This has become more and more complex the more I did it, functions can return two types, I often have to manually specify the returned type when I call the function for example and code become harder to read and write.

Is this a bad practice to add an optional `option` parameter to a function that allows someone to specify the type of the returned value they want?

```
   async balanceOfBatch(
      accountsAddresses: string[], 
      resources: ResourceName[], 
      options?: { resultAsUint256?: boolean, resourcesAsId: boolean }
   ) {
        const resourcesIds = resources.map(resourceName => bnToUint256(ResourcesToken.constants.RESOURCES_NAMES_TO_IDS[resourceName]));
        const { balances } = await this.contract.call("balanceOfBatch", [accountsAddresses, resourcesIds]);

        let balancesBatch: { [accountAddr: string]: { [resource in ResourceNameOrId]?: BigNumber | Uint256 } } = {};
        for(let i = 0; i < accountsAddresses.length; i++) {
            const key = options?.resourcesAsId ? ResourcesToken.constants.RESOURCES_NAMES_TO_IDS[resources[i]] : resources[i];
            balancesBatch[accountsAddresses[i]] = { 
                ...balancesBatch[accountsAddresses[i]],    
                [key]: options?.resultAsUint256 ? balances[i] : uint256ToBigNumber(balances[i])
            };
        }

        return balancesBatch;
    }
```

If it is, how do you manage such optionality?
Do you make one function for each like `balanceOfBatchIdUint256`, `balanceOfBatchNameUint256`, `balanceOfBatchIdBigNumber`, `balanceOfBatchNameBigNumber` ?
Or do you set one standard from the beginning and stick to it all along removing optionality?

Comment: Is the question how to type such a function or is it "best practice"?

Comment: I'm wondering how could I handle this following the good practices